# How do I schedule/trigger the web deployment tool to sync IIS webservers?

Tags: iis, files, synchronization

I need to sync a number of IIS6 webservers in a farm. I currently use [ViceVersa](http://www.tgrmn.com/) (with the VVEngine service) which does a good job of keeping files in sync but I'd like to move to the Microsoft [web deployment tool (msdeploy)](http://www.iis.net/extensions/webdeploymenttool). That way, the configuration stays in sync too.

So, the question is how do you schedule/trigger the synchronization?

- Do you use the Windows scheduler?
- Is there something built in to the web deployment tool service that I've missed?
- Something else?

Ideally, the synchronization would be triggered by a change on the primary webserver.

Answer (score 2):

Owais Shaikh, of the Web Deployment Team, has written an article about [syncing servers in a farm using msdeploy](http://blogs.iis.net/moshaikh/archive/2009/04/26/web-server-change-notification-or-web-server-compare-or-multi-server-sync-in-a-web-farm.aspx).

I haven't tried it yet but I'll be sure to report back when I do.

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to msdeploy, but I use SureSync (by SoftwarePursuits) to keep IIS6 servers in sync. It's your typical replication software, on crack.